# I can't store my DatePicker componen's value inside my form class

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, event-handling

I am beginner in react.js apps and i have my DatePicker component inside my form class.I am trying to update and store my selected date with handleChange but i don't know what's datepicker's value and i am not sure how to do it,since i imported it as a component.Sorry if i couldn't explain it very well i am beginner in react apps

```
   constructor() {
    super();
 this.state = {

      formData: {
    //i have other states here but this is the one i am having trouble with 
    //updating data
         bookTime: {
          data: "",
          name: "bookTime",
          category: "DatePicker",
          everFocused: false,
          isValid: true,
          startDate: new Date(),
          extra : {
            label:"Randevu Tarihi*",
            help: "Geçersiz Alan!"
          }
       },
     }
   };
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

This form class's code is not mine but i am trying to add a datepicker into it and i am trying not to change too many things since
it's not my code. handleChange method doesn't belong to me and that's
why i am trying to update my data with using this format.

```
handleChange(e) {
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(e.target.value)
    let name = e.target.name;
    let category = e.target.getAttribute("category");
    let startDate = e.target.getAttribute("category");

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      formData: changeHandler(prevState.formData, val, name, category,startDate)
    }));
  }
```

changeHandler method is this;

```
export const changeHandler = (data, val, name, category) =>{
 // Update the field value and get the field to validate (and name of that field)
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key, idx) =>{
     if (key === name) {
       data[key].data = val;
         return; 
       } 
    }); 
return findAndValidateField(data, name, category); 
};
```

This div is inside my form class,i didn't declared a className because i don't know what does it affects exactly

```
 <div
                  className={"" + (bookTime.isValid ? "" : " is-danger")}
                >
                <div>
                 <DatePicker className="turkish"
                   locale={tr}
                   selected={bookTime.startDate}
                   onChangeRaw={this.handleDateChangeRaw}
                   showTimeSelect
                   minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 7)}
                   maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 22)}
                   minDate={subDays(new Date(), 0)}
                   timeFormat="HH:mm"
                   timeIntervals={60}
                   dateFormat="HH:mm,d MMMM yyyy"
                   timeCaption="Saat"


                   name={bookTime.name}
                   category = {bookTime.category}
                   onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}

                  />
                  </div>
```

I want datepicker's selecteddate's value to be updated and stored like other form states in the form

Comment: Can you please create a minimal example at https://codesandbox.io/? So there is a working example. What do you get in the `console.log` in your `handleChange` method? What is `changeHandler` doing? I'm not seeing the code. Are all parameters correctly available in that function?

Comment: I have the error of "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined and the change handler method is this;                                                                                
  export const changeHandler = (data, val, name, category) => {

 // Update the field value and get the field to validate (and name of that field)
 Object.keys(data).forEach((key, idx) => {
    if (key === name) {
   data[key].data = val;
   return;
    }
 });

  return findAndValidateField(data, name, category);
};